# How to select text in an element before the particular child element

Tags: xslt

In my xml document, i have this below code. I need to select the text that is present before `<br/>` only. How to do that?

```
<div id='win0divDERIVED_SCC_AD_ADDRESSLONG$0'><span class='PSLONGEDITBOX' id='DERIVED_SCC_AD_ADDRESSLONG$0'>123 Main Street <br />
Boise, ID 83702</span>
</div>
```

I mean i need only '123 Main Street' not '123 Main Street Boise, ID 83702'

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="span">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

`//div[@id = 'win0divDERIVED_SCC_AD_ADDRESSLONG$0']/span[@id = 'DERIVED_SCC_AD_ADDRESSLONG$0']/text()[1]` should do.